# Meaning of "足生やす"

Tags: meaning, phrases, word-usage

I was wondering if the above is some kind of expression or set phrase? I saw this in in a novel actually where the speaker was remarking about his opponent in battle who was summoning hundreds of soldiers loyal to him.

Edit: The line where the phrase in question is present goes like this

> こりゃ足生やした一個の『国』や。

Comment: I don't get it very much either. Do you have the exact context?

Comment: Huh, that's a creative depiction for a large mass (I'm praising). Can you add the information to your question?

Comment: Added. So you have a good idea what this means?

Answer (score 3):

This 足生やした not an idiomatic expression, but simply "(which) has grown legs" or "(which) has legs". 足 is "foot" or "leg", and 生やす is "to grow" or "to wear (a beard, etc)". He said the crowd of soldiers is almost like a walking country. This is a rather unique metaphor.